# NHibernate logging question

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, logging, log4net

After doing some analyzing of our web site, we discovered that NHibernate logs an awful lot.
Logging is set to WARN and should not log. Does NHibernate still prints debug messages even if logging level is not met?

See included picture:

[image]

Comment: can you post your log4net config as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to you log4net config just for NHibernate

```
<logger name="NHibernate">
    <level value="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have definied a logging configuration for a given namespace ? We can redefine the log level with this simple addition to our configuration

```
    <logger name="MyApp.Project.SomeNamespace.Foo">
<level value="WARN" />
</logger>
```

Alternatively, we can set the log level for the entire namespace or even the entire project
with this configuration.

```
<logger name="MyApp.Project">
<level value="WARN" />
</logger>
```

Could you provide your log4net configuration ?